# Copy rows starting from certain row till the end using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy values of one excel and create a new one with required format. Say i need to copy columns from B11 to BG11 and rows will be till the end.( i don't know how to find the end of rows). And I have column heading in b7 to bg7. In between there are unwanted rows and i don't need it. So in the new excel i want column headings(which is from b7 to bg7) as first row and the values from b11 to bg11 till the end.

This is my first excel Macro. I don't know how to proceed. So with references from some stackoverflow question and other site, i have tried the below code. but it is not giving the required output.

```
Sub newFormat()

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“B” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

Sheets("MySheetName").Range("B7:BG7").Copy
Sheets("MySheetName").Range("B11:BG11").Copy


Workbooks.Open Filename:=”C:\Users\abcd\Documents\Newformat.xlsx”
Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

this may be simple. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you trying to do? `1` Why are you opening the file in a loop? `2` Why are you copying two range one after the other in a loop? which is the one that you are trying to copy? `3` Well, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Kindly ignore my code. It is not working. I have just tried something. Since i don't have any idea about `macros` i didn't know how to use it. If u didn't get my question(1st paragraph), let me know. i'll update

Comment: I have a fair idea but wanted to be sure before posting an answer. So the new header and that one row `B11:BG11` you want to paste in `Sheet1`? If yes then a quick question. does the sheet1 of new file already has data in it?

Comment: No ,New sheet doesn't have any data in it. it will have the first row as `B7:BG7` as heading and from 2nd row it should take values from `B11:BG11` till end of the availble rows.

Comment: See the answer that I posted. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things...

1. Do not use `Integer` for rows. Post `xl2007`, the number of rows have increased and `Integer` can't hold that. Use `Long`
2. You do not need to select a range to paste on it. You can directly perform the action.
3. You do not need to use a loop. You can copy ranges in two chunks
4. Work with objects so Excel doesn't get confused by your objects.
5. Since `Sheet1` is empty, you don't need to find the last row there. Simply start at `1`.
6. To output the data to new workbook, you have to use `Workbooks.Add`

See this example (**Untested**)

```
Sub newFormat()
    Dim wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, erow As Long

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HW SI Upload")
    '~~> Find the last row in Col B
    LastRow = wsI.Range("B" & wsI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Open a new workbook
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set wsO = wbO.Sheets(1)

    '~~> The first row in Col A for writing
    erow = 1
    '~~> Copy Header
    wsI.Range("B7:BG7").Copy wsO.Range("A" & erow)

    '~~> Increment output row by 1
    erow = erow + 1

    '~~> Copy all rows from 11 to last row
    wsI.Range("B11:BG" & LastRow).Copy wsO.Range("A" & erow)

    '~~> Clear Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '
    '~~> Code here to do a Save As
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: New sheet is coming without any data.`MysheetName` should be the sheet name from which i'm copying right? Should i change `sheet1`?

Comment: What is the name of the sheet where you want to copy?

Comment: so replace sheet1 with that name :)

Comment: Fine :) but Now it is not generating any sheets :( I think i'm missing something..It will create in same workbook or different workbook?

Comment: Where is the sheet "HW SI Upload"? in "Newformat.xlsx"?

Comment: The paste the code in a module of the workbook which has "MySheetName" and then simply run it. The data from "MySheetName" will be pasted in `HW SI Upload` of `Newformat.xlsx`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89350/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-crazy2crack).

Answer (score 1):

Different but the same

Rename the sheet

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, Hrng As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("MySheetName")

    With sh
        Set Hrng = .Range("B7:BG7")
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("B11:BG" & LstRw)
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\abcd\Documents\Newformat.xlsx"

    Set wb = Workbooks("Newformat.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    Hrng.Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Rng.Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    ws.Name = sh.Name    'renames sheet
    wb.Save
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u...Where should i give `mysheetname`?